# How do I concatenate the value of two variables into the name of another variable?

Tags: python, concatenation, python-3.4

For example

```
i='a'  
b='b'  
i+b='dog'  
print (ab)
```

Expected result: 'dog'
received result: 'Error: can't assign to operator"

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not recommended to do, you can update `globals`:

```
i='a'  
b='b'  
globals()[i+b] = 'dog'
print (ab) # 'dog'
```

---

Another (not recommended) way of achieving the same result is using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt):

```
exec "ab = 'dog'"
print ab
```

---

A better way to achieve dynamically changing key-value pairs can be achieved by using a dictionary:

```
mapper = {}
mapper[i+b] = 'dog'
print mapper['ab'] # 'dog'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> i='a'
>>> b='b'
>>> locals()[i+b] = 'dog'
>>> print(ab)
dog
```

I ... uhh ... hope this helps.

Comment: You can't (reliably) assign to `locals` in Python

Comment: This only works because `locals()` returns the globals namespace when not in a function. You cannot alter `locals()` in a function.